# SBT task gets executed multiple times

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sangria

In a Play project, a SBT task has to generate a JSON file after each compilation.

```
lazy val generateSchema = taskKey[Unit]("Generate schema.json file")
fullRunTask(generateSchema, Compile, "models.GenerateSchema")
generateSchema <<= generateSchema triggeredBy (compile in Compile)
```

But once the compilation is done this task gets executed multiple times. And it also gets executed many times even when the page is refreshed after the compilation. I think the task gets executed when each class is compiled. Is there a way to make the task run only once after a compilation and not to run when the pages are just refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to either use `sourceGenerators` or `resourceGenerators` as those are only run once per compilation, see the [doc here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Combined+Pages.html#Generate+sources).

On top of those, you will most likely also need to use [`watchSources`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Combined+Pages.html#Configure+the+sources+that+are+checked+for+changes) on the sources from which you generate your schema.json file. That way the (re)source generators will be triggered again when there's a change to the underlying source files.